# Selenium Java - trying to click button

Tags: java, button

I am trying to click a button that that has the below HTML.

```
<button title="XXYZ" class="clsBarButton" id="tbCodeBookI10" hidefocus="true"
    onmouseover="changeTBC(this)" onmouseout="changeTBC(this)" onmousedown="changeTBC(this)"
    onmouseup="changeTBC(this)" onclick="OpenReference('i10codebook'); resyncTabs();" type="button">
</button>
```

I tried the following different lines in my code but all of them throws no such element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='tbCodeBookI10' and class='clsBarButton2']")).click()

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body.clsBody.clsAJAXBody div#Toolbar
button#tbCodeBookI10.clsBarButton")).click();
```

Comment: Maybe it means "no such element" ?

Comment: What HTML does the button have? Empty text, i.e., no button at all? *confused*

Comment: The CSS class does not match. You're looking for `clsBarButton2` and the button actually has `clsBarButton`. Besides, why look by XPath if you have a unique element `id`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine

```
driver.findElement(By.id("tbCodeBookI10")).click();
```

If it keeps on failing as you suggest in your comment, check two things, that the HTML is a valid HTML, and that your button is not within an iframe (in which case you would first need to switch to the iframe)

For switching to iframe the following code should work

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
    WebElement yourIframe = driver.findElement(By.name(*THE NAME OF YOUR IFRAME*));
    driver.switchTo().frame(yourIframe);
```

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"tbCodeBookI10"}

Comment: edite in an answer, obviously the issue is not with the selectors

Comment: looks like the HTML is valid. Yes, my button is in an iframe. Here's my code: 
driver.switchTo().window(popUpWindow);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("tbCodeBookI10")).click();

Comment: ok, getting somewhere, that's why your getting exceptions, I've updated my answer for switching to iframe. Is it an iframe inside a popup, cause this code is switching to popup window